# ListView adapter gets confused when convertView is recycled

Tags: android, listview

I have a straight forward BaseAdapter for my ListView. It downloads a JSON feed and displays the data in the rows. There is a ViewHolder which contains the views and a data object called "Story". Everything works just fine.

However, after some scrolling of longer lists, I notice two things.

1) My log shows that the adapter is reloading the feed when scrolling further down. This is strange, as I put the whole JSON array into a variable, so why does it have to reload?

2) More importantly, after some scrolling back and forth, the rows contain the wrong "Story" objects. Here are the relevant parts of the getView routine:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    Story story = stories.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        //create holder
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.story_list_item, parent, false);
        holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.story_list_title);
        holder.dateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.story_list_date);
        holder.story = story;
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.story_list_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else  {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }       
    // configure the view       
    holder.titleView.setText(story.title);
    return convertView;
}
```

Simple enough. Now the strange thing is that I can fix the problem **by eliminating the if statement `if (convertView == null)`** (and, I presume, eliminating the row recycling as well).

But will I not run into memory problems this way? Why does the plain vanilla version not work?

Thanks for your help.
Regards, 
S

Comment: I don't see where the JSON feed is downloading, but it's possible that when you scroll fast enough a view will get recycled before its first feed is done downloading. Then the second feed's download will start, and if it finishes first it can then be 'overwritten' in a sense when the first download does complete.  Here's a blog post on how this can happen with respect to downloading and displaying images in a listview: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Comment: Thanks I will definitely pursue that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that you're only assigning

```
holder.story = story
```

when `convertView == null` ? Consider moving `holder.story = story` to just after your `convertView` if-case and it should work a lot better. Btw, do you even need to store the "story" inside your view holder? Typically that pattern should only be used to store Views and view state information, not the data of the actual position.

Comment: That's it, thanks. But how **do** you actually transmit the data? Just as text in the various text views, etc? How about an image url to be loaded by a different view, where would you put that? Thanks again.

Comment: Transmit between Activities? If you are using a ContentProvider you typically pass an Uri for the clicked item, for JSON I'd send the relevant information in the Intent extras (which would be populated, in your case, from the "stories" array). Implement Parcelable for Story or just write it to the extras `Bundle` and send it in the Intent?

Comment: That's what I am doing - sending the data in the Extras bundle. But I found Parcelable a real pain and full of errors - never got it to work properly. So I am using many lines of code to send each attribute of my Story... Coming from iOS, this is really quite awkward.

Comment: Maybe you should try `public class Story implements Serializable` - in most cases this works just fine for intra-process communication with Intents.